# How can I change a build step status in Team City?

Tags: teamcity-8.0

Is it a way to override the build status in `TeamCity` based on the result of a test?

We have the following setup:

1. Deploy application
2. Run a test that validates that the application installed correctly.
3. Run test batch1
4. Run test batch2

Our problem is that we did not find a good way to skip running the tests from step 3 and step 4 if the test that validates the version failed.
This is because, even if the test fails, the step status is still successful. Is there a way to override the step status?

Comment: What sort of step is `Step 2`? E.g. Can you get it to return a non-zero exit code? Also, is the test result from `Step 2` interpreted by TeamCity? If so, and the test fails, TeamCity should already realise that the step failed.

Comment: Step 2 is running a CodedUi test, which is basically an Ms test. The exit code of the step is successful even though the test fails. because the actual step was completed.